# SEO страниц товаров

Tags: php, html, seo, реклама, продвижение

Доброго времени суток. В интернете множество сайтов, на которых что-то продаётся. И у каждого товара есть своя отдельная страница.

Я себе это представлял так: в БД у каждого товара есть уникальный ИД номер. На сайте при клике в поиске или каталоге на какой-либо товар берётся ИД номер товара и передаётся с помощью GET специальному обработчику php, который ищет в БД по ИД и выводит информацию о товаре. Вроде бы всё просто, аккуратно и быстро.

Но возникает вопрос, а как быть с SEO. Ведь при таком подходе (если я ничего не путаю) роботы поисковых систем не смогут увидеть, какие товары есть на сайте. Они увидят только пару страниц и всё. Ведь каталог и информация о каждом товаре выводятся только при непосредственном обращении к ним. Фактически на страницах сайта нет информации ни об одном товаре до момента обращения к этому товару.

Так как же быть? Как это организовывается и т.п? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Бот обойдёт все ссылки которые есть на сайте и не закрыты для индексации. Он обращается не к серверной структуре вашего проекта а скомпилированной. Он как любопытный пользователь, жмёт на всё что видит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополнительно к представленным ответам. Для поисковой оптимизации веб-сайта е-коммерции хорошим решением будет создание разметки **[структурированными данными](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=ru)** с использованием библиотеки **[Schema](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)**. Для главной веб-страницы (индекс-веб-страница) возможно применение разметки **[WebSite](http://schema.org/WebSite)**. Для описания вашего веб-бутика вы можете применять атрибуты **name** - например, название веб-сайта, **alternateName** - если название веб-бутика отличается от названия веб-сайта, **description** - общее описание веб-бутика с указанием сектора товара/товаров, например: *Товары для детей*, или что-то подобное, **disambiguatingDescription** - этот атрибут является суб-описанием, для уточнения описания, например: *для детей до 10 лет*, **potentialAction** - для призыва к потенциальному действию, например: *покупайте одежду для ваших бебиков в нашем бутике*. В этом классе разметки много других атрибутов, применение которых помогут поисковикам понимать ваш веб-сайт. Применяя атрибут **mainEntity**, вы можете, применяя вложение, перейти к разметке каталога товаров или секторов товаров. Пример вложения: `<div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">...</div>` Для этого подходит разметка **[OfferCatalog](http://schema.org/OfferCatalog)**. Пример разметки:

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<header itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<a href=https://example.ru><h1 itemprop="name">Имя бутика и/или веб-сайта</h1></a>
</header>
<section itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
<h2 itemprop="name">Наименование каталога товаров или раздела товаров</h2>
<p itemprop=description>Описание товаров ли раздела данного каталога.</p>
<ul>
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<a href=...><h2 itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><span itemprop="name">Наименование продукта</span></h2></a>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</main>
```

Обратите внимание, что в указанном коде применена фрагментация кода с **[семантическими элементами ХТМЛ5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)**. Далее вы можете перейти к разметке каждого отдельного продукта, используя класс разметки **[Product](http://schema.org/Product)**. Здесь имеются множество элементов для подробного описания продукта: вес, высота, ширина, цвет, категория потребителей, производитель и так далее. Примеры разметки смотрите внизу. Для повышения доверия потенциальных покупателей к вашему веб-бутику, размечайте контактную информацию о вашем предприятии с классом разметки **[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization)**: юридическое имя предприятия - **legalName**, для идентификации вашего бизнеса используйте атрибуты **leiCode**, подробнее смотрите **[ISO 17442: Структура кодов LEI](https://www.gleif.org/en/about-lei/iso-17442-the-lei-code-structure)**, **isicV4**, подробнее смотрите **[Международная стандартная отраслевая классификация всех видов экономической деятельности, Rev.4](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/cr/registry/regcst.asp?Cl=27)**, **taxID**, **vatID**, емейл, телефон(ы), contactPoint и так далее. Используйте сочетание семантической разметки ХТМЛ5 и разметки структурированными данными. Проверяйте исходный код ваших веб-страниц на **[валидаторе ХТМЛ5](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)** (выбор фильтра outline показывает внизу структуру веб-страницы), проверяйте структурированную разметку на **[тестере Гугл](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**, проверяйте структуру веб-страниц на **[HTML 5 Outliner](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)**. Структурированная разметка используется для богатой выдачи в результатах поиска (**[rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-content)**), для голосового поиска, для технологии Гугл - Гугл Ок, для машинного обучения.

Answer (score 2):

Для достижения хороших результатов по SEO, Вам необходимо заложить в структуру БД следующие поля

- Название товара
- Заголовок товара (H1)
- Meta Title

(В целом указанные поля ПОЧТИ одинаковы по смыслу, однако иногда возникают нъюансы и лучше сразу заложить это в архитектуру, чем потом лепить костыли)

- Meta Description
- Краткое описание (выводится в категории)
- Большое
  описание (выводится на странице товара)
- Картинка.

Это необходимый минимум.

Далее - поисковые роботы в первую очередь узнают о страницах сайта по ссылкам, для этого, как уже было отмечено выше, все ссылки должны быть в нативном формате (a href= ... ) Попав хоть раз на сайт поисковый робот начинает ходить по ссылкам, обнаруженным на странице и постепенно заносить их в свой индекс.

На главной странице у вас будет список категорий товаров, верно? Вот по ним бот и начнет ходить - еще хорошей практикой является размещение на главной каких либо акционных товаров. Далее зайдя в категорию робот увидит список товаров в категории, а зайдя в каждый - собственно и сам товар, в самом товаре также является хорошей практикой размещать ссылки на другие товары по типу "С этим товаром покупают".

Кроме того можно помочь роботу, во первых [добавить сайт в поисковые системы вручную](http://www.raskruty.ru/poiskoviki/addurilka.html) , создать файл [sitemap.xml](https://www.sitemaps.org/ru/protocol.html) в котором будут перечислены все страницы Вашего сайта (внизу по ссылке есть пример) и добавить его в [robots.txt](https://www.mysitemapgenerator.com/webmaster/2.html), ну и вишенка на тортике - это [микроразметка](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/schema-org/what-is-schema-org.xml).

В качестве примера хорошего построения интернет-магазина обратите внимание на [SimplaCMS](http://simplacms.ru/), посмотрите его фронт и админку, я думаю многие вопросы прояснятся.

Всех благ.

Answer (score 1):

Глубоко мыслите поэтому возникает желание помочь :-) Сразу скажу что я не SEO но имею большой опыт общения с ними. 
В 99.99% случаев поисковое  продвижение сайтов (магазинов в том числе) ведется для Google и в русскоязычном сегменте для Яндекса, поэтому нужно четко представлять, что эти системы хотят от вашего сайте, чтобы присвоить его страницам хороший ранг и выдавать пользователям ссылки на них в результатах поиска. Хорошие ответы на эти вопросы дадут специалисты по SEO, это очень большой объем знаний, который к тому же требует постоянного совершенствования.

Первое, что нужно сделать, пока сайт находится в разработке и не готов к продвижению - запретить индексацию роботами - в корневой папке сайта создать файл robots.txt и записать туда 1 строчку disallow all, до тех пор по крайне мере, пока подобные вопросы у вас отпадут. 
Далее начинается затратная часть - найдите хорошего специалиста по SEO, объясните ему про сайт и пусть он напишет стратегию продвижения - это комплекс мер по внутренней и внешней оптимизации сайта, подход к формированию внейшей ссылочной массы, требования по объему и качеству текстовых блоков и пр. Из стратегии должен следовать примерный эффект продвижения и главное бюджет - как долго и как много денег вы будете тратить на продвижение - покупку ссылок, написание статей, использование рекламы и пр. (бесплатно не получится). Можете попросить это сделать 2-3 SEO и выбрать на основании предложенной стратегии оптимальный для вас вариант по эффекту (который кстати может быть и не достигнут) и бюджету.

Далее нужно выполнить все рекомендации SEO по внутренней оптимизации - это целый комплекс мер. Потом только включить индексацию роботами в robots.txt и начинать тратиться на ссылки и рекламу.

А что касается непосредственного вопроса - робот понятия не имеет (и не желает иметь), как формируются страницы на сайте - лежат ли они статично, или какой-то скрипт из базы их собирает и склеивает. Он оценивает результат - различные объективные параметры страниц - скорость загрузки, качество верстки, мета-теги, объем и уникальность текстового содержимого и еще примерно 943 критерия для Гугла и 1032 для Яндекса :-)
А чтобы поисковик дошел до товара - он должен при обходе сайта найти ссылки на него из других страниц, причем ссылки должны быть правильно оформлены, через `<a href="url, не js!!!"> ...</a>`

Есть множество инструментов, которые эмулируют работу поискового робота и указывают рекомендации по оптимизации - [Google WebMaster's Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=ru), [MOZ](https://moz.com/tools), [Nibbler](http://nibbler.silktide.com/), и [десятки других](https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/33164/6-SEO-Tools-to-Analyze-Your-Site-Like-Google-Does.aspx#sm.00001nygp75hquegkxmpeyuuzvxms)

Answer (score 0):

Вы описали процедуру поиска товара, когда пользователь ввыодит определенное значение и по нему ведется поиск в БД. Но для полноценного магазина необходим каталог. Получается необходимо для каждого товара из БД сделать отдельную страницу, где будут выведены все его характеристики и каждый товар должен иметь отдельную ссылку (страницу). В БД можно записать все МЕТА поля, характеристики, описания и категорию, к которой товар относится. Вот из этих данных и собирайте страницу. Роботы ПС проиндексируют эти страницы и будут о них знать. А при поиске пользователем товара, при наличии результата, выводите уже готовую страницу с необходимым товаром