# Cсылки из сайта в поиске google

Tags: seo

Как добавить ссылки из сайта при поиске в Google, например

[image: снимок экрана с обведёнными ссылками на разделы сайта под сниппетом в результатах поисковой выдачи]

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и касается SEO-шников и их инструментов воздействия на поисковую выдачу. Читайте профильные статьи, есть ряд рекомендаций, которые Вы и сами можете найти в Гугле или Яндексе.

Comment: Google ставит эти ссылки сам. Надежных рецептов создать их для своего сайта нет. В Сети можно найти некоторые рекомендации, например: http://www.bloggingwizard.com/google-sitelinks/

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения емейла и другой информации о вашем бизнесе, примените разметку структурированными данными для **[Организации](http://schema.org/Organization)**, пример:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.t-mobile.com",
  "contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-877-746-0909",
      "contactType" : "customer service",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
      "areaServed" : "US"
    } , {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-505-998-3793",
      "contactType" : "customer service"
    } , {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-877-296-1018",
      "contactType" : "customer service",
      "contactOption" : ["HearingImpairedSupported","TollFree"] ,
      "areaServed" : "US"
    } , {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-877-453-1304",
      "contactType" : "technical support",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
      "areaServed" : ["US","CA"],
      "availableLanguage" : ["English","French"]
    } , {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-877-453-1304",
      "contactType" : "bill payment",
      "contactOption" : "TollFree",
      "areaServed" : ["US","CA"]
    } ] }
</script>
```

Для отображения списка, примените структурированную разметку **[ItemList](http://schema.org/ItemList)**, например:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <h2 itemprop="name">Top 10 laptops</h2><br>
  <link itemprop="itemListOrder" href="http://schema.org/ItemListOrderDescending" />
  <p>1. <span itemprop="itemListElement">HP Pavilion dv6-6013cl</span></p>
  <p>2. <span itemprop="itemListElement">Dell XPS 15 (Sandy Bridge)</span></p>
  <p>3. <span itemprop="itemListElement">Lenovo ThinkPad X220</span></p>
  ...
</div>
```

Для отображения списка "хлебных крошек", примените структурированную разметку **[BreadcrumbList](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)**, например:

```html
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

Для списка товаров и/или связанных коммерческих предложений, примените структурированную разметку **[OfferCatalog](http://schema.org/OfferCatalog)**, например:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
  <meta itemprop="serviceType" content="Home cleaning" />
  <span itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <span itemprop="name">ACME Home Cleaning</span>
  </span>
  offers a variety of services in
  <span itemprop="areaServed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/State">
    <span itemprop="name">Massachusetts</span>, including
  </span>
  <ul itemprop="hasOfferCatalog" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
      <span itemprop="name">House cleaning</span>
      <ul itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">Apartment light cleaning</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">House light cleaning up to 2 bedrooms</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">House light cleaning 3+ bedrooms</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
      <span itemprop="name">One-time services</span>
      <ul itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">Window washing</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">Carpet deep cleaning</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
            <span itemprop="name">Move in/out cleaning</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: В вопросе - про ссылки на разделы сайта. Схема тут вообще ни при чем.

Comment: Обратите внимание на этот фрагмент предложенного кода  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.t-mobile.com",

Comment: Ну и как этим вывести 10 ссылок на разные разделы сайта, как в вопросе - "EMail - TV Packages - BT Broadband - Broadband deals" ?

Comment: Вероятно вам надо пробовать применение структурированной разметки. Эта разметка способствует "богатой выдаче" в поиске https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews . Конкретно по вашему вопросу. Вероятно надо применить ContactPoin с атрибутом email + атрибуты leiCode и/или isicV4, если это США, то атрибут naics + возможно brand + hasOfferCatalog - библиотека http://schema.org/Organization. Подробнее см. мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627051/seo-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/705151#705151

Comment: Ссылка, что вы приводите, не о том. И ответ не о том, а в целом об улучшении сайта. Почитайте вот это: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en Здесь черным по-белому написано - Google сам формирует ссылки на разделы сайта, и механизм не раскрывает. Все советы на тему, как заставить Google в выдаче формировать ссылки на разделы сайта являются домыслами, и не более того. Возможно, некоторые советы по SEO помогут, а может, и нет. Никто не знает, как сделать ссылки на разделы, кроме Google.

Comment: @KAGG Design Я согласен, что никто досконально не знаком с поисковыми алгоритмами поисковиков. Но мы можем оперировать с известными инструментами, библиотеками и предоставленной информацией. Которые я и использовал в моём ответе и комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш сайт базируется на каком-либо движке, например, WordPress, то это ссылки рубрикаторы, которые создаются автоматически при создании рубрики. К сожалению не все движки могут этим похвастаться.